# Cannot find boost_filesystem DLL when running tests

Tags: boost, dll, visual-studio-2019

The project builds a couple of executables, some static and dynamic libraries, and some test executables and libraries. The project can be build with Visual Studio for Windows 10 and also under Ubuntu. The tests have run for weeks but I had to re-build, and move, **vcpkg**, which includes the **boost** libraries. I also checked out new code trying to solve the problem.

When running a test from VS2019 in debug mode a dialog appears:

> The code execution cannot proceed because
>   *boost_filesystem-vc142-mt-x64-1_72.dll* was not found. Reinstalling the program may fix this problem.

The *dll* is in *C:\users\me\source\vcpkg\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\bin* and three other locations. Does VS2019 have a setting to look_here for libraries? They were always just found before.

Answer (score 0):

I missed the step `vcpkg integrate install`.

Answer (score 0):

I also faced this problem and fortunately I found a solution.

I'm using VS2019 and vcpkg 2022-03-09-1affd32f93b299d5a907816c328ca3ededb73a7e. Building project in **Debug** configuration

My problem was that `$(VcpkgConfigSubdir)` macro was resolving to an empty value in both Debug and Release configurations. It's supposed to resolve to an empty value in Release only, while in Debug it's supposed to resolve to `debug\`.

So, in ***Project Properties -> Linker -> General -> Additional Library Directories***
I had the value `$(_ZVcpkgCurrentInstalledDir)$(VcpkgConfigSubdir)lib` changed to `$(_ZVcpkgCurrentInstalledDir)$(VcpkgConfigSubdir)debug\lib`. I also did the same change in ***Project Properties -> Linker -> Input -> Additional Dependencies***

I posted an issue to vcpkg github with this. You can follow it from [here](https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg/issues/24017)

When they fix the problem, be sure to revert the changes.